# Slipstream Windows 7 + Service Pack 1

Tags: windows-7, service-pack

I heard that Microsoft released Windows 7 Service Pack 1 yesterday. By sheer coincidence I planned to format and reinstall Windows 7 on my PC, next week.

Is it possible merge (slipstream) the original Windows 7 installation and the new Service Pack 1 in a single [ISO image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image)?

**Note**: Bonus points if you suggest a method that works also for Windows XP.

Comment: Bonus point available if someone could suggest a method which doesn't involve installing another third-party piece of software to do it.

Comment: I was able to successfully 'slipstream' Win7 SP1 using the above method.
However...need to warn folks that the package integration could take anywhere from 25 to 40 minutes to complete!  I thought it had locked up for a while, but then I saw more activity.

When it was all said and done, I re-installed Win7 and sure enough, it was SP1 right off the bat.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

WARNING: YMMV. I think we're close, but not quite there yet. These instructions have worked for some people, but I'm getting an error on the last step. So I think we're missing something. It's getting late here, I'm going to flag this as a community wiki. Perhaps you can sort out what I've missed.

## Slipstreaming Windows 7 Service Pack 1

Windows 7 slipstreaming is not officially supported. You can use third party tools to accomplish the task. You can also do it yourself manually by unpacking the cab files, editing three text files, and using `dism` command to update the installation packages. Here's how to do that step by step:

1. Copy `install.wim` from your installation disc to your hard drive.
2. Go to the [download Windows 7 Service Pack 1](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199583) webpage on the Microsoft website, and then click **Continue**.
3. After you have passed the "Genuine Advantage" test, you can choose to download either `windows6.1-KB976932-X64.exe`, or the 32-bit version `windows6.1-KB976932-X86.exe`
   [image: Service Pack Download]
4. Extract the contents of the service pack with the `-x` command. Example: `windows6.1-KB976932-X64.exe -x`
   [image: Service Pack Download]
5. Extract the contents of `windows6.1-KB976932-X64.cab` with a tool like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) (any compression utility that supports cab will do).
6. Extract the contents of `NestedMPPContent.cab` into the same folder.
7. Open `update.ses` in notepad and change `Absent` into `Installed` under `OfflineInstall`. It should look like:

   ```
   <Tasks operationMode="OfflineInstall">
       <Phase>
           <package id="Windows7SP1-KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514"  targetState="Installed"/>
       </Phase>
   </Tasks>
   ```
8. Open `update.mum` and `Windows7SP1-KB976933~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.17514.mum` (or the 32-bit equivalent) in notepad and change `allowedOffline="false"` to `allowedOffline="true"`
9. Extract all the language cab files `KB976933-LangsCab0` through `KB976933-LangsCab6`, overwrite files if prompted.
10. Launch a command prompt with Administrative privileges.
    [image: Run command prompt as Administrator]

    Let's assume you stored the extracted service pack files in a folder called `C:\sp1`. Create a new folder called `C:\offline`, and note the location of `install.wim` which should be in the sources folder in your Windows 7 installation disc contents. Use the following commands (change folder names where necessary:

    ```
    DISM /Mount-Wim /WimFile:C:\win7-contents\sources\install.wim /Index:1 /MountDir:C:\offline
    DISM /Image:C:\offline /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\sp1
    DISM /Unmount-Wim /MountDir:C:\offline /Commit
    ```

TODO: add instructions for creating bootable disc

Comment: This is primarily based on a guide posted by pOcHa on mdl forums: http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/22807-DVD-with-SP1-integrated-into-Windows-7?p=337159&viewfull=1#post337159

Comment: When I try to extract SP1 with 'windows6.1-KB976932-X64.exe -x' it throws me the error: ... 'is not a valid Win32 application'. Is it possible extracting this file in another way on a Win32 machine or this operation can be done only on an X64 machine?

Comment: You'll have to use a system running 64-bit Windows to extract the 64-bit update.

Comment: @ Drake, I tried using 7 zip, it extracted some files but not all.

Comment: fyi there error I got when I try to use /Add-Package is `Processing 1 of 1 - Package_for_KB976932: The specified package cannot be added
to an offline image.` .. `Error: 0x800f082e`. And by the way, any sensible person should just be using an official slipstreamed image from MS. This is just a fun diversion.

Comment: @Briankb care to transform this post into a nice blog post for the Super User blog?

Answer (score 10):

I know this requires having an account, but pre-slipstreamed DVD images are available for MSDN and Technet subscribers.

Comment: Or your can browse the Technet Subscriber Downloads to find the listing for the image you want, then Google for its SHA1 hash to find torrents of it available for download.  As long as the SHA1 hash matches Microsoft's listing, you'll know that it hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: This is the most sensible option. Unless you are customizing your installation disc, you may as well grab the official image!

Comment: Agreed - great to know we can download official (slipstreamed) images from MSND/Technet. Wikid :)

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 slipstreaming is not officially supported at this time. However, you can use a third-party program called [RT7Lite](http://www.rt7lite.com/) to slipstream the service pack for you. Here are some [step-by-step instructions](http://windows7support247.blogspot.com/2011/02/slipstream-windows-7-sp1.html).

You can [download Windows 7 Service Pack 1](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199583) from Microsoft's website, as long as you pass the "Genuine Advantage" test.

Comment: A more extensive tutorial is in [How to Slipstream Windows 7 SP1 to Create a Bootable USB, Installation DVD, or ISO File](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/145343-slipstream-windows-7-sp1-into-installation-dvd-iso-file.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can follow the instructions in *[How To Slipstream Windows 7 SP1 Into Installation DVD ISO](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-slipstream-windows-7-sp1-into-installation-dvd-iso/)*.

Comment: Actually, you can't. vLite was made for Vista. Windows 7 slipstreaming is not officially supported. http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/150023-problem-with-vlite-12-and-win7-sp1-msdn/

Comment: Revised answer with RT Seven link instead. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Pick one of:

- vLite (Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008)
- RT Se7en Lite (Windows 7)
- 7Customizer (Windows 7)

They were found in *[List of remastering software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_remastering_software)*.

Comment: Remastering/Customizing is not the same as Slipstreaming a Service Pack, RT7 lite Beta version 2.6.0 is the only one that can do that at the present time. Vlite only works on Vista for SP slipping. It appears 7Customizer has been abandoned.

Comment: @Moab I think there is now a version called NTLite that has a win 7 slipstream feature.

Comment: @jiggunjer yeah its been a while since I messed with that type of software, thanks. https://www.ntlite.com/features/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to download the official Windows 7 SP1 installation ISOs straight from Microsoft's disk image distributor. See [How can I reinstall Windows 7 if I lost my installation DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd/272144#272144) for details on how to obtain these images.