# Is there official Windows 7 with service pack 1?

Tags: windows-7, service-pack

I am looking Windows 7 with service pack 1 but i am not sure that it is officially exist or not. If it is exist so where can i download it ?

Comment: You can get it from MSDN if you have subscription.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - unfortunality i have no . Another source ?

Comment: I think that you can get a windows disk with SP1 if you buy a new one. I'm not aware of any other official way to get the disk. You may try searching for Microsoft's sites for hashes of the official image and then try to get one that matches from various sites that facilitate possibly illegal sharing of data with your neighbors, but it sort of beats the "official" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN if you have a subscription.

Or Slipstream your own : [Slipstream Windows 7 + Service Pack 1](https://superuser.com/questions/249275/slipstream-windows-7-service-pack-1)