# Injecting SP1 into our Windows 7 wim

Tags: windows-7, service-pack

We're trying to update our WIM image - so no need to install latest updates following imaging a new laptop. We are getting the following error message through dism after trying to add-package:

```
An error occurred - Package_for)KB976932 Error: 0x800f082f

DISM failed no operation was performed.
```

I can provide logs if required?

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes...Provide logs.

Comment: the next two best work arounds which will save you time, is to either install it as an app in a MDT task sequence OR just grab the Win7 w/ SP1 wim file directly from microsoft's distributor digital river.

Comment: Ramhound - another user is currently on machine - will provide logs later today

Comment: MDT Guy - Sorry I should have explained, we have a custom build wim which contains many apps - so option 2 would not be an option. 

How would I go about installing SP1 as an app in MDT task sequence?

Thanks
Alex

Comment: 0x800f082f = CBS_E_EXCLUSIVE_WOULD_MERGE Why are you not downloading an official ISO which already has the Sp1 integrated? Google for digital river links.

Comment: Hi magicandre, we already have an image which we are happy with - which contains lots of software packages. As such if we were to download an ISO containing SP1 we would need to recreate the image. Best option is to inject SP1

Comment: I think is already answered here
http://superuser.com/questions/249275/slipstream-windows-7-service-pack-1