# Windows 7 Enterprise with Service Pack 1

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, service-pack

I've just downloaded Windows 7 Enterprise evaluation from Microsoft and the ISO file says it's the 7600 version. Isn't there a Windows 7 Enterprise installation with Service Pack 1 already slipstreamed?

Comment: There might be you can also create one yourself

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/249275/slipstream-windows-7-service-pack-1?rq=1